# Raise and catch user defined exceptions

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I use the `RAISE EXCEPTION '...' USING ERRCODE='....'` quite a lot in my code, as I can use the error code in my C# code. However, I would like to use it now in my plpgsql code, like this:

```
BEGIN
    ...
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Something is wrong' USING ERRCODE='S0001';

EXCEPTION WHEN 'S0001' THEN
    -- Handle code S0001
END;
```

But that doesn't work. How can I catch and process my own thrown exceptions in plpgsql ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your exception handling clause should look like this:

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN SQLSTATE 'S0001'
   THEN
      ...
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`sqlstate`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING), e.g.:

```
drop function if exists test();
create or replace function test()
returns int language plpgsql as $$
begin
    raise exception using errcode = 50001;
    return 0;
    exception when sqlstate '50001' then
        return sqlstate;
end $$;

select test();

 test  
-------
 50001
(1 row)
```